# NSInternalInconsistencyException with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I am trying to use a custom header view for header in my table view controller.
I have created a class for my custom uitableviewheaderfooterview.

What is in my custom header view? It adds a button to default header view.

I am able to use this custom header view with few uitableviewcontrollers.. But it would seem that I am not able to use it for some controllers at all.
First table view controller from navigation controller; using my custom view is ok.
But if I push to next view, I will run into problems fast..

I am not posting here my custom class, due to the reason of it's length and because this can be simulated with simpler variation as well. I use storyboards, in storyboard I have a navigation controller and tableview controller, and my custom view is used there. A cell pushes to another tableview controller. This also uses the custom class, but hangs immediately when it gets pushed with:

```
 2014-07-27 13:10:04.365 Hours[41029:3941001] *** Terminating app due
 to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a
 background thread.'
 *** First throw call stack: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108beec35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib   
 0x000000010ab76a1c objc_exception_throw + 45   2   CoreFoundation      
 0x0000000108beeb6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205  3   Foundation 
 0x000000010924decc -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] +
 89     4   UIKit                               0x0000000109f8a2d9
 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 452   5   UIKit                               0x0000000109f8a0ec -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
 _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 197  6   UIKit                               0x0000000109f89d88 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
 _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 404   7   UIKit                               0x0000000109f8a881 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
 _layoutEngineCreateIfNecessary] + 53   8   UIKit                               0x0000000109f7f53f -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
 _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabled:] + 22    9   UIKit                               0x0000000109f7ff20 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) addConstraints:]
 + 263  10  Hours                               0x0000000108282db4 _TFC5Hours16EventTypesEditor9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_22viewForHeaderInSectionSi_GSQCSo6UIView_
 + 7012     11  Hours                               0x0000000108283e56 _TToFC5Hours16EventTypesEditor9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_22viewForHeaderInSectionSi_GSQCSo6UIView_
 + 70   12  UIKit                               0x0000000109a0bb7e -[UITableView _delegateViewForHeaderInSection:] + 45     13  UIKit                               0x0000000109a0f124 __96-[UITableView
 _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]_block_invoke
 + 97   14  UIKit                               0x000000010998ab9e +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65   15  UIKit                               0x0000000109a0efcf -[UITableView
 _sectionHeaderView:withFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]
 + 511  16  UIKit                               0x0000000109a0f8c0 -[UITableView _sectionHeaderViewWithFrame:forSection:floating:reuseViewIfPossible:willDisplay:]
 + 85   17  UIKit                               0x00000001099ef030 -[UITableView _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow:] + 2582    18  UIKit                               0x00000001099f06a5 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
 + 3714     19  UIKit                               0x0000000109a05fea -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213  20  UIKit                               0x0000000109992d25 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
 + 519  21  QuartzCore                          0x00000001097a9058 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150     22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010979dc7e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
 380    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010979daee
 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24     24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010970c8e6
 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242    25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010970d9f2
 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390     26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010970dc27 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 199     27 
 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b45f54f
 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 86  28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b45c479 _pthread_exit + 111  29  libsystem_pthread.dylib   
 0x000000010b45c3e9 pthread_exit + 30   30  Foundation                  
 0x0000000109282e51 __NSFinalizeThreadData + 0  31  Foundation         
 0x0000000109262e41 __NSThread__main__ + 1214   32 
 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b45b899 _pthread_body +
 138    33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b45b72a
 _pthread_struct_init + 0   34  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010b45ffc9 thread_start + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating
 with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is a variation of custom view that causes this issue:

```
    let customSection = 0

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView! {
        switch section {
        case customSection:
            var h = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
//          var h = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("Header") as UITableViewHeaderFooterView // This also caused trouble

            h.contentView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
            h.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

            var t = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
            t.text = "Hello"
//          t.sizeToFit()
            t.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            h.contentView.addSubview(t)

            h.layoutSubviews()

            var views = NSMutableDictionary()
            views.setValue(h.contentView, forKey: "|")
            views.setValue(t, forKey: "label")

            h.contentView.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[label]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
                ])

            h.contentView.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[label]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
                ])


            return h
        default:
            return super.tableView(tableView, viewForHeaderInSection: section)
        }
    }
```

Possibly.. But not sure. Not familiar with threads..
How the magic happens? This is how.. When you tap the cell with push action..
didselectrowatindexpath is activated and it does the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell!.selectCell()
    }
```

Now, to selectCell..

```
override func selectCell() {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to: nil, from: nil, forEvent: nil)

        if self.buttonSelector != nil {
            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC)))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(self.buttonSelector, toTarget:self.buttonTarget, withObject: self)
                })
        }

    }
```

selectCell is included as a empty function in uitableviewcell's extension..
and finally, what is set as buttonSelector? Function in uitableviewcontroller doing the push.. It's here:

func eventTypeDetails(cell: UIMenuItemCell) {
    NSLog("Details for %@", (eventTypes.objectAtIndex(cell.tag) as NSArray).objectAtIndex(1) as String)

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventTypeCell") as SettingsActionCell
cell.eventTypesButton!.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

}

I am starting to see that it's my override func selectCell() that is causing this, but how to fix this..??? Simple fix propably is to change didselectrowatindexpath to do the pushing accordingly to index paths.. But I wonder if this could be fixed so I could maintain my original way of doing things? After all, I've got many custom classes based on uitableviewcell to help making form like views and stuff.. All with autolayout and all using this same approach (some of them have buttons or other kind of actions)

Comment: Are any of your controller methods that handle pushing the view controller or similar being executed in a background thread?

Comment: Possibly.. But not sure. Not familiar with threads..

Comment: That would certainly be my guess based on the stack trace you've given. It would appear that the view is being created and laid out outside of the main thread which is causing the issue, so see if you can find out if something is pushing it into a background thread. Alternatively force that rendering into the main thread. You could have also stumbled into a swift/ios 8 bug in theory

Comment: I doubt that.. I am pretty sure that I have fabricated this bug with my own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'm not entirely sure what you're code is meant to be doing but I think you're overcomplicating things.

If you're just trying to push a view controller then this is definitely the case. In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you should be able directly invoke the push method of the navigation view, there's no need to call anything on the cell directly.

If you want to keep code the way you've got it that ok, but your `selectCell` function is where the issue lies as it seems to essentially be starting a background thread to do the work. Doing any kind of UI work in a background thread is a big no-no in iOS.

Try changing it to

```
if self.buttonSelector != nil {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(self.buttonSelector, to: self.buttonTarget, from: self, forEvent: nil)
    })
}
```

For the target you'll most likely need to use NSInvocation, but just make sure its on the main thread

Comment: I had to add one more argument for the performSelectorOnMainThread, waitUntilDone: <Bool>, on Xcode 6 beta 4, but it still doesn't work.. performSelector methods are unavailable..

Comment: But this works better:     NSThread.performSelectorOnMainThread(self.buttonSelector, withObject: self, waitUntilDone: false)

Comment: But as it doesn't have a target.. It errors with unregocnized selector sent to class 0x1022e7808

Comment: Thanks.. Already better, but there's no withObject available.. It's forEvent: <UIEvent?>

Comment: and you ment: var control : UIControl = UIControl() ?

Comment: this is better, but doesn't send the sender along, therefore I don't get tag of sender..    control.sendAction(self.buttonSelector, to: self.buttonTarget, forEvent: UIEventTypeTouches)

Comment: I could avoid my problem with not trying to do it this complicated, but there's just that I made effort for these classes and standardizing them for multiple projects, so I gladly would love to get solution by doing it this way instead of using directly didselectrow.. Sorry for all the trouble.. Have to go to work soon, while working, cannot do this and it means I'll be trying again on next weekend if I don't get back sooner.. I didn't tell this so people would hurry, I just don't want to upset anyone waiting to see if they got my problem solved..

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what the code is doing. You retrieve a cell when tapped, then call the `selectCell` action, which then in turn looks up another cell and performs an action? Why the need for 2 cells? Have altered code again, see if that works

Comment: Thanks. That worked, just had to add let value = 1 because block bugged about something (nothind is done with value, but error is gone with that..) - I have created a bunch of classes to help build user interface, textfields, switches, etc.. These are all cells, they all have or have a possibility to default action and selectCell contains this, these actions are different depending on type of cell, some cells are "links".. to actions like this one is.. And cell carries a property containing target and action and all these cells are set in the same way.. They are supposed to make gui building

Comment: very simple and standard. With few lines you can add a cell with textfield and title, list.. So many things, all aligned and using auto layouts.. That idea wasn't maybe my brightest, but this is how I built it so it's a bit complicated in the inside, but outside, it's simple as cell.setTarget(self, "action:").. So it's all good. Once again, million thanks for solving my trouble :)